# Why I am getting sqlite3error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to reuse an sqlite statement in my application in a method. Here's the relevant code

```
if(getsets_statement == nil){
    const char *sql = "SELECT DISTINCT num,roll FROM mytable WHERE cls like ? and divname like ?";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &getsets_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: Failed to prepare stmt with message '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }       
}

sqlite3_bind_text(getsets_statement, 1, [cls UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(getsets_statement, 2, [divname UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

while(sqlite3_step(getsets_statement) == SQLITE_ROW){

    setNumber= sqlite3_column_int(getsets_statement, 0);        

    roll = sqlite3_column_int(getsets_statement, 1);

    [numArr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:setNumber]];
    [rollArr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:roll]];
}

sqlite3_reset(getsets_statement);
```

The statement executes perfectly the first time it is called. But the next time I call this method, I get a `sqlite3error`. The values of `divname` and `cls` are present (did an `NSLog` and checked) but I don't understand why I am getting this error. I get the error at the first `bind_text` statement.

This is in the gdb console

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
(gdb) where
#0  0x9041857f in sqlite3Error ()
#1  0x9041acea in vdbeUnbind ()
#2  0x9041b2c8 in bindText ()
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you sure that cls and divname are valid objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure nothing else is actually the issue (is the database being closed somewhere else?  Is the `getsets_statement` pointing to the same object?  Has it been finalized?).  Then try using NULL or SQLITE___STATIC instead of SQLITE_TRANSIENT.  Since `[NSString UTF8String]` returns data that doesn't need to be freed (by you), it obviously doesn't need a destructor, and it will stay valid until after your function exits, at which time you're done running the statement anyway.

Comment: The docs say, "If the fifth argument is the special value SQLITE_STATIC, then SQLite assumes that the information is in static, unmanaged space and does not need to be freed. If the fifth argument has the value SQLITE_TRANSIENT, then SQLite makes its own private copy of the data immediately, before the sqlite3_bind_*() routine returns." I would think either should be fine here, but SQLITE_TRANSIENT is the surefire-bet (albeit at a performance cost), because a copy is made immediately.

Comment: Was calling finalize. That was causing the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @lostInTransit you should put that as your answer, since your comment here is the solution to the same issue I was having.

Comment: @gdbj glad it helped you. This answer pointed me to the right direction, that is why it was marked correct. And it covers almost all possible reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call [sqlite3_reset](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_reset) and [sqlite3_clear_bindings](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_clear_bindings) on the prepared statement before attempting to reuse it.  Also, you should really check your return codes.

Comment: I thought a reset was enough. Anyways, that is what all the Apple examples use. But I will give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Tried adding sqlite3_clear_bindings. It returns SQLITE_OK. But I am still getting the error.

Comment: in order to reset bindings to null, you do have to call clear_bindings but in this case it's irrelevant because the statement has only 2 parameters and both are being bound on each invocation.

Comment: What exactly returns SQLITE_OK?  As I said, you should check /every/ return value, and tell us the first one that fails to return SQLITE_OK or crashes.

Comment: i think the strings in the bind_text may be bad? There really just isn't enough information here, lost. As Matthew says, post more context.

Comment: Jason, I thought about that.  But sqlite should be making an internal copy immediately every time bind_text is called (because of SQLITE_TRANSIENT).  And he said divname and cls remain valid.

Comment: Hmm... I'm still not convinced. It has to be a freed variable getting accessed. Maybe it's the getset_statement?

Comment: I get a SQLITE_OK for every statement there is until I do the bind the second time. I think it might be what Marty is saying. BTW, what does the finalize statement do? And when should it be used?

Comment: did you call finalize? that destroys your getsets_statement and is used when you don't want it anymore. that would definitely be your problem which is why i kept asking you about that... it is certainly NOT SQLITE_TRANSIENT. if you're only preparing your statement once, you must not call finalize until you're cleaning everything up and you won't use that statement again.

Comment: That was it. I was calling finalize before the object was getting dealloced. Thanks Marty and Jason

Comment: NP lost: that error EXC_BAD_ACCESS always means that you're dereferencing bad memory, so you have to look for objects/pointers that have been destroyed before their time ;)